# Product of two multivariate t densities

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, t-distribution

Does the product of two multivariate t densities result in the density of a known distribution, that is easy to simulate from?

Comment: What constitutes being "known"? Just having a name? Or are there particular properties that should be known about it?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess being able to simulate from it quickly is the main property that would be useful.

Comment: It might be best to add that information to the question.